# Appending zeros to original value in Kendo Numeric text box

Tags: kendo-ui

Appending zeros to original value in Kendo Numeric text box

I am entering the value `0.0000000000001` in Kendo numeric textbox.
but its changing as `0.00000000000010000000`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
                                .Name("Amount")
                                .Decimals(15)
                                .Format("n")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @maxlength = "15" })
                              )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. So - is this a problem for you? What problems are being caused? Do you have a question about it?

Comment: Try Changing Decimals(8), also can you let me know the datatype of Amount in your model

Comment: Even i tried to reduce the decimal to 2@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Amount)
                                .Name("Amount")
                                .Decimals(2)
                                .Format("n")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @maxlength = "15" }). still its not working.Data type of the amount is decimal.